# Django Query ManyToMany

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to do a query to select top 5 users with more likes in their posts.

My models are:

```py
class Post(ModelBase):
     title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=255)
     description = models.TextField()
     finished = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='post_author')
     likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='PostLike',)
     tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='tags')

     def total_likes(self):
         return self.likes.count()

class PostLike(ModelBase):
     post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have this, but it does not work for me correctly. Instead of telling the Likes of the users' post, count the Likes that each user has given.

```
users = User.objects.annotate(likes_count=Count('postlike', Q(post__is_active=True)))\
        .order_by('likes_count').reverse()[0:5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of annotating `Count` of `postlike` you need to annotate the count of `post_author__likes` (traversing relations by the related name you have set):

```
users = User.objects.annotate(
    likes_count=Count(
        'post_author__likes',
        filter=Q(post_author__is_active=True)
    )
).order_by('-likes_count')[0:5]
```